# How to redirect / into basePath in Next.js config?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Every time that user enter into `/` I want to redirect into `basePath` that I already set.

Here is my `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/docs',
}
```

So every time I enter path `/` I want to redirect into `/docs`.

Here is what I've tried.

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/docs',
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/docs',
      },
    ];
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/docs',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

The problem is this `rewrites` and `redirects` are working with `basePath` only.

For example

```
async redirects() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/test',
            destination: '/hello',
          },
        ];
      },
```

I enter into `/docs/test` it will redirect into `/docs/hello`.

But I want `/` to go to `/docs`.

Comment: Conventionally you could also make use of `routers` to redirect to the desired path when a user reaches `/`  (default index) path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`basePath: false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#redirects-with-basepath-support) option to disable the automatic `basePath` prefixing of `source` and `destination`.

```js
module.exports = {
    basePath: '/docs',
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/',
                destination: '/docs',
                basePath: false,
                permanent: false
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This will correctly redirect `/` path to `/docs`.

The same applies to `rewrites`, if you were to use that instead.

Comment: You should also set the "permanent" property to true or false.

Comment: Rewrites -
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Redirects - 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects